# Passing arguments to Custom Hook onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple react app in which I am fetching the data using `jsonplaceholder` API and displaying the data with a delete button. I have a `function deleteUser` inside the `User.js` component. Now I want to make this deleteUser function a general function so I created a separate hook for it.

Now I want to pass arguments to that custom hook but I get the error

> React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom
> React Hook function react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

**userDelete.js**

```
import { useFetch } from "./useFetch";
export const useDelete = (userName) => {
  const { data, setData} = useFetch();
  const newData = data.filter((dataItem) => dataItem.name !== userName);
  console.log(newData);
  setData(newData)
};
```

**useFetch.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useFetch = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`;
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      setData(data);
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error", error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return { loading, data, setData };
};
```

**User.js**

```
import { useFetch } from "../Hooks/useFetch";
import { useDelete } from "../Hooks/useDelete";

const Users = () => {
  const { loading, data, setData } = useFetch();
  const deleteCallback = useDelete(data);

  const deleteUser = (userName) => {
    const newData = data.filter((dataItem) => dataItem.name !== userName);
    console.log("newData", newData);
    setData(newData);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Custom Hook Example</h1>
      {loading && <h4>Fetching Data...</h4>}
      {data.map((data, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          style={{
            border: "2px solid red",
            width: "fit-content",
            margin: "0 auto"
          }}
        >
          <p>Name: {data.name}</p>
          <article>Email: {data.email}</article>
          {/* <button onClick={(e) => deleteUser(data.name, e)}>Delete</button> */}
          <button onClick={() => useDelete(data.name)}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      ))}
      {data.length === 0 && (
        <>
          <p>No Items to Show</p>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Users;
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: For which file does it give error?

Comment: User.js where I am invoking the useDelete() function

Comment: Hint: Where do you call `deleteCallback`?

Comment: Try to return something from useDelete hook

Comment: @Spikatrix actually I was trying that approach by referring this stackoverflow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58821668/react-custom-hooks-in-callback but it did not work for me

Comment: you can't do this: `<button onClick={() => useDelete(data.name)}>Delete</button>`

Comment: @Martin So how can I make it a general function I mean the deleteUser function in my  User.js component works as expected but I want to extract that logic to a separate file or component. How can I do that.

Comment: prepare a callback in `useDelete` and return that. The user click can trigger the callback.

Comment: No that doesn't work out. How can I do that any documentation ? Something like useEffect you mean ?

Comment: Why you wanna do this? You don't want to maintain separate `data` state here, you just wanna filter. A custom hook isn't a good choice in this case.